# Listview showing previous selection [ANDROID]

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, android-adapterview

In my app i am showing some items in list view, each row have one name and one tick image. Tick image only shows up when item is selected(checked), The selection is working fine but the problem is when a new item is selected tick of previously selected item doesn't goes invisible. How this can be fixed? Any help will be appreciated
here is my code

**Adapter**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> responseList;

    private LinearLayout parent_choice_list_container;
    private TextView item_name;
    private ImageView iv_choice_list_item_selected;
        public ListAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> responseList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.responseList = responseList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setSelectedIndex(int ind) {
        selectedIndex = ind;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return responseList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, null);
        }
        parent_choice_list_container = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.parent_choice_list_container);
        item_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        iv_choice_list_item_selected = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_choice_list_item_selected);
        iv_logo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_blog_category_logo);
      if (responseList.get(position).isSelected()) {
            iv_choice_list_item_selected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            iv_choice_list_item_selected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }            list_item_name.setText(responseList.get(position).getName());
        return view;
    }
}
```

**FragmentPart (Item Click Listener)**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    response.get(position).setSelected(true);
    ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.androhub.com/android-listview-radiobutton/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using a [`CheckBox`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html).

Have you tried conditionally updating the `View`s visibility depending on whether the item `isChecked` (and *not* `isSelected`)?

Answer (score 0):

you should set tag for each image to keep track of its state (0 = not selected/invisible , 1 = selected/visible) , e.g:

```
 if (responseList.get(position).isSelected()) {
        iv_choice_list_item_selected.setTag(1);
    }
```

and you can add this :

```
 if (iv_choice_list_item_selected.getTag() == 1) {
        iv_choice_list_item_selected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        iv_choice_list_item_selected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: no its not working, it insteads showing the tick image on random positions without even them getting selected